# SharePoint Libary takes 10 minuntes to load on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, grouping

Hope you're well;

I have sharepoint libary which takes 10 minutes to load. there 1500 files.

How do I make it faster to load.

kind regards,
Anees

Comment: Create Sub folders and move the documents into them. I have done with a Document Library with Folder structure of 32000 PDFs . avg size of PDF was 50 MB some time 800 MB

Comment: I wouldn't create sub-folders, it's not really good practise.  Your scenario does not match with Vinit's either, since you have far fewer documents.  How many results are showing in the view; is it loading up all 1500 files at once or are you displaying something like batches of 30 files at once?

Comment: How many GB are your files??

Answer (score 0):

Have a think about the 'architecture' of how these files could be structured (would making several document libraries make more sense?).  You could add the links to the site collection navigation, so it is still easy for users to find what they need e.g. 1-500; 501-1000; 1001-1500.

Also the Sharepoint content database uses SQL, SQL does slow down when really large files are stored in it.  These large files are known as BLOB files (Binary Large Object Files).  It could be that removing these BLOB files from your SQL database would speed up the performance of Sharepoint.

Here are a couple of links to get you started in your research:

[MS BLOB files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/rbs-planning)

[SE BLOB post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216930/when-to-use-rbs-and-when-not-to)

Search through lots of SP SE BLOB-related [questions & answers here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=BLOB)

Answer (score 0):

Normal procedure is to open a support case so they can investigate if something is wrong in your SPO tenant.

You can use Fiddler to monitor requests and responses to see what is failing. Fiddler will let you know exactly how long it takes to load the page, and break down each and every resource that is also loaded in order to render the page.

You can also reduce this issue by creating more views or using "group by" function for better manage your files. You can refer to this article:

http://bugfree.dk/blog/2017/06/19/optimizing-sharepoint-list-view-load-time-performance